# jQuery how to update range number of rows in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table like this.

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="count"><td class="int">1</td>...</tr>
    <tr class="hide"></tr>
    <tr class="count"><td class="int">2</td>...</tr>
    <tr class="hide"></tr>
    <tr class="count"><td class="int">3</td>...</tr>
    <tr class="hide"></tr>
</tbody>
```

I used jQuery for dinamic webpage. when user removed a row from list, i need update number range at client again.
this is my code. but my result wrong expected.

```
$('.count').each(function() {     
    var ind = $(this).index()+1;
    $(this).find(".int").html(ind);
});
```

*Note for rows that class `hide` not for view on browser, it for other point.
please help me to find it.

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).index()` will not work in these case, because hidden elements also have index. Try like following.

```
$('.count').each(function(i) {     
    var ind = i + 1;
    $(this).find(".int").html(ind);
});
```